# Android background color appears different on the device from the same color in an image on the same view

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-imageview

Update: I was able to fix the problem by using a JPG image instead of a PNG image. Now my question is if it is possible for me to solve this type of problem by changing ImageView attributes instead of converting to JPG. All of my images are in PNG, although this may be the only case of background matching in use in my apps, except for white.

I have a layout background view that is the same color as the background color in an image (+/- 1%). It appears find on a Galaxy S3, but on the Neutab Air7 the background color is rendered differently than the image (ImageView) color, creating a square box. What can I do to fix this? It is not that the device renders colors "wrong", as that would cause them both to be the wrong color. I suspect that something is wrong with the image or ImageView.

When a screenshot is taken on the Air7, all looks fine:

[image]

but on the device the image appears as a distinct square.

Source image (PNG):

[image]

Working image (JPG):

[image]

Comment: Post both the images.

Comment: No, the problem is with the device. There is no budget android device that doesn't come with some kind of flaw. You just found one with the Air7. However there is something you can do to fix this: make the image transparent instead of it having the same background color. Replicating the background color is always a bad idea.

Comment: And converting your images to jpg is not a fix. Png is just fine. The Air7 is just a crappy tablet.

Comment: @Piyush posted the images. I took a picture of the device, but it did not come out well enough to post. As to the other user's comment here, converting to JPG is a superior fix than adding transparency, seeing as bother are hacks and the one is easier. I found another post that said transparency leaks through on some devices, so thats how I came up with the idea for JPG.